# How to edit sub-panel record like we create record using "QuickCreate" in SugarCRM 6.5.x?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM 6.5.x CE version. I am trying to edit the existing record in subpanel, but when I click on edit button, it opens in a same window as a "Full Form". But I want to edit the record like we create in "**QuickCreate**" mode.

I know, we can change mode of creating records in subpanel from "Full Form" to "Quick Create" mode, but I don't know or not seen anything on net of changing mode of editing records in subpanel. Kindly guide me here.